# Func type with a parameter and void return

Tags: c#, lambda, function-pointers

I wanted to know why this doesn't work ? The compiler says that void cannot be used with `Func` type.
In that case what are my options

```
  Func<int,void> func1 =  (x) => { Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Func<T, TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) delegate has one parameter and returns a value of the type specified by `TResult`, you can't use `void`, because it specifies that method doesn't return any value and can't be used as type argument.

You can use [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8) delegate in your example, it has a single parameter and doesn't return a value

```cs
Action<int> action = (x) => { Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); };
```

Since `x` parameter isn't used, you can just use parameterless [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.8) delegate

```cs
Action action = delegate { Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `Action<int>`

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp oh, it doesn't expound verbosely, but: pretty sure it answers the question, terse as it may be

Comment: Well S.O. rules are clear... and if I do exeptions, the brainless robotic audit of S.O. gets me at some point ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an `Action`, but the problem can be overcome by returning for example a null object.

```
Func<int,object> func1 =  (x) => { Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); return null;};
func1(2);
```